# error, the type argument for method IQuerable<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying type argument explicity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

this is my query

```
List<Models.adModel> ads = context.ads
    .Join(context.Locations, 
          x => new { x.lid, x.cid },
          y => new {y.lid,y.cid }, 
          w => new Models.adModel { adid=w.adid,... })
     .ToList();
```

But I am getting  following error error

> the type argument for method IQuerable<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>
> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying type argument explicity

on this link [LINQ to SQL error on .Join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630559/linq-to-sql-error-on-join)

it says that field names are dfferent in Key parameters to Join but in my case lid, and cid are same in both keys.

Please let me know why this error is causing. And how to resolve  it

I renamed the Key parameters names to Keys parameters to check if this to firm that the link applies on my query Keys too but its giving same error

**Update**
This is my ad entity in EF

```
 public partial class ad
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ad()
        {
            this.images = new HashSet<image>();
        }
    
        public int adid { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
        public int lid { get; set; }
        public int cid { get; set; }
        public int catid { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<image> images { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my Location entity

```
public partial class Location
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Location()
        {
            this.ads = new HashSet<ad>();
        }
    
        public int lid { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public int cid { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ad> ads { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is country entity

```
public partial class Country
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Country()
        {
            this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
        }
    
        public int cid { get; set; }
        public string country_name { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add `ads` and `Location` entities?

Answer (score -1):

I had to do like this

```
List<Models.adModel> ads = context.ads.Join(context.Locations, x => new { x.lid, x.cid }, y =>
                        new {y.lid,y.cid }, (w,k) => new Models.adModel { adid=w.adid }).ToList();
```